# How to close LCD in D3300 after each shot

Tags: nikon-d3300

All:

I just got D3300, one thing really annoying is its parameter menu:

each time after I shot, the LCD will light up and show menu, I wonder how can I close that setting, just manualy control when open that LCD?

Thanks

Comment: Unless Nikon has significantly changed this, I think this is basically the same as [Is there a way to force the Nikon D40's rear LCD panel to stay off?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-nikon-d40s-rear-lcd-panel-to-stay-off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this off in the camera menu.

MENU > WRENCH > Auto info display > OFF

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this saves me. I turns out not a good student.